# How do I turn debug logging on for Wink classes in an Apache Wink web service?

Tags: java, logging, apache-wink

I have a web service built on Apache Wink (1.1.3), running under Tomcat, started from Eclipse for debugging. How do I turn full logging on for some Wink classes?

For a start, I just tried turning it on for all of Wink with these lines in the logging.properties file of the Tomcat conf directory:

```
org.apache.wink.level = FINEST
org.apache.wink.handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
```

I also tried putting these lines in another file and referencing that file with `-Djava.util.logging.config.file=....` Neither of these worked.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Wink uses [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/) for logging. Meaning you should configure it with your favorite logger.
For example adding slf4j-jdk14.jar to your classpath will send the logs to the JDK's native logger.

I suggest you read the [slf4j two pages manual](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html).

Comment: Thanks @Tarlog, and apologies for the delay in responding. I looked at the log output being produced, and it contains some entries for Wink, such as: _238 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.apache.wink.common.internal.application.ApplicationFileLoader - The runtime is loading the JAX-RS application from jar:file:/Users/ossher/projects/sse1/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/com.ibm.cfoi.services.samples.hello/WEB-INF/lib/wink-json4j-provider-1.1.3-incubating.jar!/META-INF/wink-application_

Comment: Continuation: My problem is that I can't find the control file to modify (or don't know where to create one) to get more detailed levels of logging for selected Wink classes. Can you help with that? Thanks!